# Is there a way to edit track info directly using squeezebox server?

Tags: music, squeezebox, squeezecenter

I've got a server running Squeezebox server (v7.4.2).  Is there a way to edit track info using the Squeeze server software ?  My other options are to connect to the directory with the music and edit using another piece of software, which is a faf if I just want to correct something I've noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about the track info as it appears in the server software, or about the ID3 metadata (tags) on the file?

SqueezeCenter (aka Squeezebox server) isn't designed to edit tags.  It assumes you've done your tagging work in some other tool.  The Linux version doesn't necessarily have write access to the files; only read access is necessary.  I double-checked with the [list of plugins](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/PluginsAudio) and there doesn't appear to be a single one for editing tags.

The SlimDevices wiki has a pretty good [Beginners Guide to Tagging](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/BeginnersGuideToTagging) that has a good list of tagging software you might consider, as well as info on which tags SqueezeCenter will use when it scans a file.

Comment: Fair enough.  I do most of my tagging on my laptop using Amarok or Picard (less so Amarok since 2 - ughh !), It's just annoying when you see a track with an error in squeeze, you want to fix it straight away....